# What is appropriate coordinate transformer for Lambert Azimuthal Equal Area to Google maps in Geotools?

Tags: java, geotools

I need to extract the coordinates from the GeoTiff file (that was provided by European Soil Agency for Spain) and display them in Google Maps.

For that, I wrote simple Java code

```
    public static void readTiff1(final String pathToTiff) {
        var file = new File(URLDecoder.decode(TiffParser.class.getResource(pathToTiff).getFile(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        var format = GridFormatFinder.findFormat(file);
        var reader = format.getReader(file);
        var cov = reader.read(null);
        var gridRange2D = cov.getGridGeometry().getGridRange();
        var googleMapsTransformer = CRS.decode("EPSG:3857");
        var target = cov.getCoordinateReferenceSystem();
        var gf = new GeometryFactory();
        var targetToWgs = CRS.findMathTransform(target, googleMapsTransformer, true);
        int count = 0;
        for (int j = gridRange2D.getLow(1); j < gridRange2D.getHigh(1); j++) {
            for (int i = gridRange2D.getLow(0); i < gridRange2D.getHigh(0); i++) {
                if (count++ > 10)
                    System.exit(1);
                var coord = new GridCoordinates2D(i, j);
                var p = cov.getGridGeometry().gridToWorld(coord);
                var point = gf.createPoint(new Coordinate(p.getOrdinate(0), p.getOrdinate(1)));
                var wgsP = JTS.transform(point, targetToWgs);
                System.out.format("(%d %d) -> POINT(%.2f %.2f) -> POINT(%.2f %.2f)%n", i, j, point.getCoordinate().x,
                        point.getCoordinate().y, wgsP.getCentroid().getCoordinate().x, wgsP.getCentroid().getCoordinate().y);
            }
        }
    }
```

The output of this program is the following

```
PROJCS["PCS Name = GRS_1980_IUGG_1980_Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area", 
  GEOGCS["GCS Name = GCS_GRS_1980_IUGG_1980", 
    DATUM["Datum = unknown", 
      SPHEROID["Ellipsoid = GRS80", 6378137.0, 298.257222101]], 
    PRIMEM["Greenwich", 0.0], 
    UNIT["degree", 0.017453292519943295], 
    AXIS["Geodetic longitude", EAST], 
    AXIS["Geodetic latitude", NORTH]], 
  PROJECTION["Lambert_Azimuthal_Equal_Area"], 
  PARAMETER["latitude_of_center", 51.99999999999999], 
  PARAMETER["longitude_of_center", 10.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_easting", 4321000.0], 
  PARAMETER["false_northing", 3210000.0], 
  UNIT["m", 1.0], 
  AXIS["Easting", EAST], 
  AXIS["Northing", NORTH]]
```

And the list of the coordinates

```
indexes  source                          target
(0 0) -> POINT(2635950.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3503460.95 10202813.83)
(1 0) -> POINT(2636450.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3502415.88 10203547.81)
(2 0) -> POINT(2636950.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3501370.61 10204281.72)
(3 0) -> POINT(2637450.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3500325.13 10205015.57)
(4 0) -> POINT(2637950.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3499279.46 10205749.36)
(5 0) -> POINT(2638450.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3498233.59 10206483.08)
(6 0) -> POINT(2638950.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3497187.51 10207216.75)
(7 0) -> POINT(2639450.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3496141.24 10207950.34)
(8 0) -> POINT(2639950.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3495094.76 10208683.88)
(9 0) -> POINT(2640450.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3494048.09 10209417.35)
(10 0) -> POINT(2640950.00 5421950.00) -> POINT(-3493001.21 10210150.76)
```

What is the appropriate coordinate transformer for the google maps api?

Comment: The input data is using EPSG:3035. Try that because the list of coordinates now doesn't make sense for 3035 or EPSG:3857.

Comment: So, I've tried the EPSG:3035 (as the target coordinate system) and got the following output: `(0 0) -> (source) POINT(2635950.00 5421950.00) -> (transformed) POINT(5421950.00 2635950.00)`. Still, when I enter the transformed coordinates (`POINT(5421950.00 2635950.00)`) into google maps, they don't belong to Spain ...

Comment: Those values match the answer I get from gdaltransform - so it's possible the data is reporting the wrong projection or the data is just not in Spain

Comment: Which numbers are you talking about? =) I am sure that this geotiff has Spanish coordinates. Is it possible to get the projection from geotiff?

Comment: Was the data an extract from one of ESA's datasets? Can you provide a link to the dataset? I randomly looked at a dataset and its metadata did say EPSG:3035. Can you query the geotiff for its extent?

Comment: https://esdac.jrc.ec.europa.eu/resource-type/soil-point-data -- from this site I've obtained data. I cannot post the geotif since its size is around 4Gb